# Remove partial polyline

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a WordPress plugin where users can build a route map and show it on their site. In the admin panel it shows a preview of the existing route on the map, and also a marker they can drag to a new location that they want to add to the map.

The default zoom location for the map is set in Europe. But if they for example add a few stops in Australia, then only that part of the world is visible and you won't see the draggable icon anymore that is used to specify new locations, and that is a problem.

So I thought of fixing it with fitbounds, so it would always make the draggable marker and the already created route fit on the screen. The code I have does show all the locations on the map, but because I draw polylines between the visited locations, it somehow also draws a line to the draggable marker in Europe, which it shouldn't do because it's not part of the route.

You can see an example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/tijmen/HctvT/1/

Part of the code:

```
/* Draw lines between the markers */
function drawFlightPlan( flightPlanCoordinates ) {  
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: "#ad1700",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap( map );

    fitBounds( flightPlanCoordinates );
}

/* Zoom the map so that all markers fit in the window */
function fitBounds( flightPlanCoordinates ) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();

    /* Include this latlng value in europe, but I dont want a line going to that latng... */        
    var defaultLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng('52.378153', '4.899363');
    flightPlanCoordinates.push( defaultLatlng );

    for ( var i = 0, flightPlanLen = flightPlanCoordinates.length; i < flightPlanLen; i++ ) {
      bounds.extend ( flightPlanCoordinates[i] );
   }

   map.fitBounds( bounds );
}
```

The lines between the markers in Australia are fine, but the line to Europe shouldn't be there (normally there would just be a different colored marker in Europe).

I don't really understand why there is a line going to Europe in the first place. The flightPath.setMap( map ); is run inside the drawFlightPlan function. And it's not untill the fitBounds function is that I add the latlng value for Europe to the flightPlanCoordinates array.

I searched for a way to remove a partial polyline, but I can't find anything about it that works. I know how to remove all the markers or polylines, but not a single polyline part. Is that even possible?

Any ideas or suggestion how to fix this, or is this something that cannot be fixed the way I want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize `bounds` with the `LatLng` in europe instead of pushing this `LatLng` into `flightPlanCoordinates`

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/HctvT/4/

When you use a reference to an array as path for a polyline any changes to the array will affect the polyline.